# Occurrence and extraction in list item

Tags: python

I have this list of data:

```
a=[2,8,2,5,6,7,8,2,2]
```

and I get the number of occurences of each element with:

```
list=[(x,a.count(x)) for x in set(a)]

[(8,2),(2,5),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1)]
```

I want to extract the elements with an occurrence above 2 and get the array:
    [8,2]

How can I do ?

Comment: This would be easier with `collections.Counter(a).most_common()`, then you get them in descending count order. But you could do `[a for a, b in list if b >= 2]` (**note**: don't name your own variable `list`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then simply change it to:

```
list = [x for x in set(a) if a.count(x) >= 2]
```

Now your list will contain only items that their count is >= 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the variable name list because that is reserved in python but you can access the second element of a tuple just like a normal list slice.

```
new_list = [x for x in list if x[1] > 1]
```